# Downloading Image from SharePoint reduces the quality of the image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am syncing images from SharePoint User Profile and I save it in DB. The Image is saved in DB as VarBinary(MAX). The Image in SharePoint looks pretty clear. After saving in DB, we show the messages in our web app. The Problem is even though SharePoint Profile Image shows very clear, the web app image is blurred.
Any suggestions on how we could improve the message quality (as in reduce the blurr) ?

The following shows how we get the Image from SharePoint:-

```
private byte[] GetImageData(ClientContext context, string pictureUrl)
{
            //if (this.fedauthCookieContainer == null)
            //{
                Uri webUri = new Uri(pictureUrl);
                var authCookie = this.GetCredentials().GetAuthenticationCookie(webUri);
                var fedAuthString = authCookie.TrimStart("SPOIDCRL=".ToCharArray());
                var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                cookieContainer.Add(webUri, new Cookie("SPOIDCRL", fedAuthString));
                this.fedauthCookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            //}
            using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                handler.CookieContainer = this.fedauthCookieContainer;
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

                    return client.GetByteArrayAsync(pictureUrl).Result;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then after saving the image from SharePoint in our DB, we show it in our web app. The following code shows how we grab the image from DB.

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Image(string email)
        {
            string mediaType = "image/jpeg";
            HttpResponseMessage file = this.File(this.GetDefaultHeadshotImage(), mediaType);
            var imageData = await this.profileService.GetProfileImage(email);
            if (imageData != null)
            {
                file = this.File(imageData, mediaType);
            }
            return file;
        }
```

This is how we show the Image in our web app:-

```
<div class="widget-profile-user-image" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(\'' + imageUrl() + '\')' }" style="background-image: url(&quot;/home/PDSPortal/api/Profile/Image?email=XYZ.ABC-LMN@am.jll.com&quot;);">
            <div class="widget-profile-achieverStatus" data-bind="css:  achieverStatusCss, visible: achieverStatus() != 'None'" style="display: none;">
                <div class="text" data-bind="text:  achieverStatus">None</div>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your browser is probably scaling the image, introducing a blurring effect.  Is it blurry in both Chrome and IE?  I doubt this has anything to do with your DB.

Comment: @Amy - Thanks for your response. It is blurry in both IE and Chrome ? What do we do now?

Comment: Save the file to disk in `GetImageData` and see if its still blurry.  Do the same thing where you load the file from the database.  Isolate where the blur is introduced.